# HP deskjet 2540 printer not working on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hplip

I used hplip as usual, but I can't install my *hp deskjet ink advantage 2546 all in one*. How to install it?

Comment: I have the same printer. It works fine on 14.04+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of hplip in 12.04 is not recent enough for that printer so you will need to go to hplip website to get the new one which should work fine.

1. Discover the minimum version required for your printer on HPLIP install wizard http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html
2. Google the minimum hplip version and download it (in my case hplip-3.13.8.run)
3. `sh hplip-3.13.8.run`
4. Follow installation instructions but ***DESACTIVATE UPDATES***
5. Printers>add printer>select yours>Connection HPLIP>Apply